# Find the formulas of the middle point algorithm for drawing the parabola?

Tags: midpoint

Find the formulas of the middle point algorithm for drawing the parabola ? 
x^2 = 4*(a+b)*y , a,b > 0. 
Solve it according to E(East) and NorthEast(NE) ?

This is the result i got (This is writen in java frame, so its the opposite on graph)

[image: My try]

This is my try, Ok in this problem the y increases y_{k+1} = y_k + 1 every time and x_{k+1} = x_k or x_k + 1 depending on the P_k value. Here is code i tried with: If P_{k} > then ( p_{k+1} = p_k - 4*(a + b) + 2*x_k + 1; and x in increased by one x_{k+1} = x_k + 1;) else ( p_{k+1} = p_k - 4*(a + b);) , It doesn't look very well i think

Comment: This is obviously a homework/exercise question. So can you tell us what you have tried by yourself and what you are struggling with? I searched the internet for "middle point algorithm parabola" and already got some promising results.  Just copy-pasting the question is at least for me a bit to less effort on your side to be willing to help.

Comment: I'll send you what i archieved today later cause i am busy with some other things, thank you for helping.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0Onvip-j9w ... By watching this video this is my try,  Ok in this problem the y increases y_{k+1} = y_k + 1 every time and x_{k+1} = x_k or x_{k+1} depending on the P_k value.  Here is code i tried with:  If P_{k} >   then  (   p_{k+1} = p_k - 4*(a + b) + 2*x_k + 1;  and x in increased by one  x_{k+1} = x_k + 1;)  else (  p_{k+1} = p_k - 4*(a + b);) , It doesn't look very well i think..

Comment: I added the photo i got in code